# Galaxy Nexus always rotates a picture - portrait instead of landscape and vice versa

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, photos, auto-rotation

A pal of mine says his Galaxy Nexus always rotates a picture - takes it portrait instead of landscape and landscape when set to portrait. Any ideas why does it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have not faced such a issue with my GNex yet(running stock Android 4.2.2)

The orientation of the settings also depend on the orientation is set. Suppose he wants to take a photo in portrait, ask him to take the phone in portrait mode and then make the setting as portrait mode.